# Spring Cloud Stream Delayed Exchange Creation Through configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have an use case where messages has to be reprocessed with certain delay and also want to introduce exponential backoff between retries, the ReRouteDlqApplication mentioned over the documentation exactly suits my purpose.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/multi/multi__rabbitmq_binder.html

The only extra info which I need is, is it possible to configure delayedExchange as well through application.properties and binding the same with the Original queues instead of doing the same via Beans, so that there isn't need to duplicate logic across multiple error handlers(i.e one error handler per one DLQ)

Plz let me know in-case any extra info is needed.

Edit:

As per the comments received, I have deleted all the exchanges and queues and then tried afresh locally, but still am running into the below error
Error:  "received ''x-delayed-message'' but current is 'topic' "

My Properties File:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.destination=fabric-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.group=package-queue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.durableSubscription=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=package
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.autoBindDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.dlqDeadLetterExchange=
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingConsumerChannel.consumer.delayedExchange=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the consumer binding property `delayedExchange` to `true`.

The commit was added in [version 1.2](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/commit/b654afa5517058eb55d73a901354f0ea4b787cde).

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So54986375Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54986375Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.delayedExchange=true
```

and

[image]

Comment: I have tried that but no luck, I am always running into this exception "received ''x-delayed-message'' but current is 'direct' " and if I don't set the exchange type as direct then am getting the exception "received ''x-delayed-message'' but current is 'topic' " , I have the delayed message plugin installed and I have tried this after resetting the entire rabbitmq setup via the reset command

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You can't change an existing exchange type. You have to delete it first. The binder creates topic exchanges by default. If it is direct something else is creating it.

Comment: I have deleted all queues and exchanges and that's when I tried, I have also commented out setting exchangeType to direct so that by default Topic exchange will be created, but then also, I am running into  "received ''x-delayed-message'' but current is 'topic' " . I will update the question with my settings, plz review it once

Comment: I don't know what else I can say except add an example; see the edit to my answer; it works exactly as I described. You must have some other code that is declaring the exchange.

Comment: Aah yes, I have an other property at producer side, which is declaring the exchange type, I think that might be causing the issue, will debug it , thank you for the support . spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.packagingProducerChannel.producer.exchangeType=true